# Open a web page with IP Address in Java

Tags: java, uri, ip-address

In my program, the user can open a web page using his default browser. But what I possess is the IP address of the machine and not its `URL`.

I found out that a web page can be easly opened with:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

but `browse` accept `URI` object. Even a conversion URL-IP address is not a solution because I don't know what machine's URI is, I've only its IP-Address. So, is there a way to open a web page passing its IP address? Thank you a lot!

Comment: And this has ..what to do with Swing?  Even if the app. is a rich client desktop app. that uses Swing components, this question does not relate to Swing itself..

Comment: A URI can contain a domain name or an IP address. For example `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://127.0.0.1")` will work as well as `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://localhost")`. You may face two problems: the webserver delivers serveral web pages with different domains for the same IP, or the NAT-problem decribed in the answer below by aviad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IP is publically accessible (the host is not behind the NAT) you can replace the host name by the IP address in the URI.

One possible thing that can mess it up is that in your client machine in `etc/hosts` file the hostname is mapped to some other IP address.

You might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184615/resolve-host-name-to-an-ip-address) to better understand how hostname to IP resolution works.